# Testing RxJava2 - observable won't return any values

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-android

I have a problem with unit test using Robolectric and RxJava and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The problem is that code in created Observable didn't return any error or response(onCompleted and onNext is not called) I'm trying to create simple test which will be check if my CategoriesManagerInteractor get correct data from database (for database I'm using SQLBrite + SQLDelight).

Test code:

```
@Test
public void categoriesManagerTest() {

    assertNotNull(BMApp.getBriteDatabase());

    //given

    //creating expected categories and adding it to database
    List<Category> expectedCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedCategories.add(Category.FACTORY.creator.create(CategoryHelper.addCategory("Test 1"), "Test 1"));
    expectedCategories.add(Category.FACTORY.creator.create(CategoryHelper.addCategory("Test 2"), "Test 2"));

    CategoriesManagerInteractor interactor = new CategoriesManagerInteractor();
    TestObserver<List<Category>> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
    Observable<List<Category>> observable = interactor.getCategoriesObservable();


    //when
    testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).subscribe(testObserver);

    //then
    testObserver.assertNoErrors();
    assertEquals(2, observable.blockingFirst().size()); //success
    testObserver.assertComplete(); //fails
    assertEquals(2, testObserver.values().size()); //fails
}
```

CategoriesManagerInteractor method which create Observable:

```
 @Override
public io.reactivex.Observable<List<Category>> getCategoriesObservable() {
    return BMApp.getBriteDatabase().createQuery(Category.TABLE_NAME, Category.SELECT_ALL).mapToList(new Function<Cursor, Category>() {
        @Override
        public Category apply(Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
            return Category.FACTORY.select_allMapper().map(cursor);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Found a problem, awaitTerminalEvent should be after subscribing not before

Comment: just to be sure that your await works put a Thread.sleep(5000) after the subscribe